# How did Hitler's personal security work?

Tags: hitler

Considering recent events and, more generally, how top politicians move about in tank like cars and with a considerable amount of body guards it is quite surprising to see all those black-and-white clips of Hitler (with Mussolini!) travelling in an open car (or walking fully exposed in front of tens of thousands of people for the *totenehrung*) through narrow streets in cities.

Even though Hitler was popular, he was also clearly a very controversial person, and there were millions of Germans who had reason to assassinate him (which is proved by the numerous attempts on his life during his reign), still he seems to have been reasonably accessible for the general public (As a sidenote, this heightened security is a relatively recent invention. JFK travelled - although it didn't work out that good for him - in an open car. Not even a prime minister or president in a relatively non-violent country like, e.g., The Netherlands, would do that today. Iceland maybe?).

**How was Hitler's personal security handled before the war? How come he wasn't killed by his internal enemies?** Sniper rifles existed and were pretty good even in the 30s.

Comment: Isn't the answer in the question? Personal security was rare prior to JFK.  And there are significant qualitative threshold  between ""having a reason to assassinate", and "having the means"  and "carryout out intent".   Where is the prior research? how many attempts were there? How many attempts against other figures?    At least to me, the question seems to be predicated on presentist assumptions.

Comment: SS was originally designed as a personal protection force for Hitler. Nevertheless, they were not particularly successful, as there were many attempts on his life and most of the time he escaped with pure luck (or perhaps Divine Providence as Hitler believed) and not by the skill of those protecting him. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assassination_attempts_on_Adolf_Hitler

Comment: This is a very long time ago, and I recall listening to a radio documentary, in French, about Hitler's survival of one of his assassination attempts.  The person being interviewed, apparently a fairly high ranking person on his protection detail was very clear about the timing that day:   "as you can imagine, when you are doing this job, you are very aware of time".  He furthermore stated that Hitler (or his security detail) often made a point to throw unpredictability into his schedule, either by showing up late or early or by cancelling.  So, yes, he had a security detail.

Comment: Although this question has faults, I really fail to see how it is opinion-based. I would suggest focusing on getting an answer to *"How was Hitler's personal security handled before the war?"* (i.e. remove other stuff and then show some research on that question - where you've looked etc.).

Comment: Many European Prime Ministers travel in the open though indeed with security which has been a problem as some prime ministers have been more agile than their security detail. I've seen the Dutch King go for his evening walk just like anyone else in the country would (i.e., no bulletproof cars, etc).

Comment: As a starting point of your research, you can read the following: [Führerbegleitkommando – Wikipedia (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BChrerbegleitkommando) and [SS-Begleitkommando des Führers - Wikipedia (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Begleitkommando_des_F%C3%BChrers) which go into great detail.

Comment: @MarkJohnson is right, there were a number of groups tasked primarily with Hitler's protection from assassination attempts. Hitler had 15 food tasters (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margot_W%C3%B6lk). Also (besides the ones MarkJohnson mentioned): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichssicherheitsdienst